# How to install 32bit version library on CentOS6.5 system

Tags: centos

I am trying to install pysvn 32bit version in my CentOS6.5.

I tried all the below steps

1. yum install pysvn // it installed 64bit
2. yum instal pysvn.i386 // package not found error
3. I followed the steps given in the `https://centos.pkgs.org/6/epel-i386/pysvn-1.7.6-1.el6.i686.rpm.html` // it still installed 64bit version.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture for 32-bit x86 on CentOS is `i686`, you need to specify that:

```
yum install pysvn.i686
```

Comment: I tried using pysvn.i686 . I got package not found error.